# SQL-alchemy: ValueError too many values to unpack?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I have a website running with a mysql database using the sql-alchemy package that has suddenly broken. I have done some research and found that the expected issue is that the newest sql-alchemy update is handing flask-admin one more value than expected from

```
"cls, key = identity_key(instance=obj)"
```

[Source](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms-sqlalchemy/issues/9)

The suggested fix is to edit the files to accept a third item but I am unable to do this with the permissions I have on my environment.

Another answer links to a repo on github but I cannot figure out how that helps me. I'm very new to this and I don't know if I am supposed to clone the repo or how exactly to do that if I am.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is the error dump

> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,593: [2018-01-22 20:01:59,592] ERROR in app:
>   Exception on /reservation/add [GET]
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,594:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,594:
>   File "fakepath/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,594:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()2018-01-22 20:01:59,594:   File "fakepath/flask/app.py", line 1614,
>   in full_dispatch_request
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,594:     rv =
>   self.handle_user_exception(e)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,595:   File
>   "fakepath/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception2018-01-22 20:01:59,595:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)2018-01-22 20:01:59,595:   File "fakepath/flask/_compat.py", line
>   33, in reraise
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,595:     raise value2018-01-22 20:01:59,595:   File "fakepath/flask/app.py", line 1612,
>   in full_dispatch_request
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,595:     rv =
>   self.dispatch_request()
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,596:   File
>   "fakepath/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request2018-01-22 20:01:59,596:     return
>   self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,596:   File "fakepath/flask_login/utils.py", line 261, in
>   decorated_view
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,596:     return func(*args,
>   **kwargs)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,597:   File "/home/apoalphagammawebmaster/inventory/app/auth/views.py", line 248,
>   in add_reservation
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,597:     form=form,
>   title='Add Reservation')
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,597:   File
>   "fakepath/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template2018-01-22 20:01:59,597:     context, ctx.app)
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,597:   File "fakepath/flask/templating.py", line 116, in
>   _render
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,597:     rv = template.render(context)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,598:   File
>   "fakepath/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,598:     return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)2018-01-22 20:01:59,598:   File "fakepath/jinja2/environment.py",
>   line 1008, in render
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,598:     return
>   self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,598:   File "fakepath/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in
>   handle_exception
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,599:     reraise(exc_type,
>   exc_value, tb)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,599:   File
>   "fakepath/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,599:     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,599:   File
>   "/home/apoalphagammawebmaster/inventory/app/templates/auth/reservations/reservation.html",
>   line 2, in top-level template code
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,599:
>   {% extends "base.html" %}
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,599:   File
>   "/home/apoalphagammawebmaster/inventory/app/templates/base.html", line
>   48, in top-level template code
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,600:     {%
>   block body %}
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,600:   File
>   "/home/apoalphagammawebmaster/inventory/app/templates/auth/reservations/reservation.html",
>   line 27, in block "body"
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,600:     {{
>   wtf.quick_form(form) }}
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,600:   File
>   "fakepath/jinja2/runtime.py", line 579, in _invoke
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,600:     rv = self._func(*arguments)
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,601:   File
>   "fakepath/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html", line 205, in
>   template
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,601:     {{ form_field(field,2018-01-22 20:01:59,601:   File "fakepath/jinja2/runtime.py", line
>   579, in _invoke
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,601:     rv =
>   self._func(*arguments)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,601:   File
>   "fakepath/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html", line 123, in
>   template
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,601:
>   {{field(class="form-control", **kwargs)|safe}}
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,601:   File "fakepath/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 153, in
>   **call**
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,601:     return self.meta.render_field(self, kwargs)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:
>   File "fakepath/wtforms/meta.py", line 56, in render_field2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:     return field.widget(field,
>   **render_kw)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:   File "fakepath/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 287, in **call**2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:     for val, label, selected in
>   field.iter_choices():
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:   File
>   "fakepath/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 107, in
>   iter_choices
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:     for pk, obj in
>   self._get_object_list():
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:   File
>   "fakepath/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 100, in
>   _get_object_list
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,602:     self._object_list = list((text_type(get_pk(obj)), obj) for obj in query)
> 2018-01-22
>   20:01:59,603:   File "fakepath/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/fields.py", line
>   100, in 
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,603:     self._object_list
>   = list((text_type(get_pk(obj)), obj) for obj in query)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,603:   File "fakepath/wtforms/ext/sqlalchemy/fields.py", line
>   189, in get_pk_from_identity
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,603:     cls,
>   key = identity_key(instance=obj)
> 2018-01-22 20:01:59,603:
>   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is covered on the github issues thread - https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1588

Basically, the `flask-admin` pip package is out of date, in regards the latest `sqlalchemy` pip package.  In that specific area,

```
cls, key = identity_key(instance=obj)
```

`sqlalchemy` is now returning 3 objects, but `flask-admin` is only expecting 2, hence the error.

The *real* solution for this is to wait until a new `flask-admin` version is uploaded to pip, until then, you've a few options.

1. *Manually* go in and edit that `fields.py` file
2. As detailed in that issues thread, limit `sqlalchemy` to version `1.2.0b3`.  You can do this in your requirements.txt file, or manually with a pip upgrade install, `pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy==1.2.0b3`
3. As the fix is in `flask-admin`'s master branch in their github repository, install that version of `flask-admin` with the pip location of `git+https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin`.  Again, you do this in your requirements.txt file, or with a pip upgrade install, `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin`.

My personal preference, and what I've done, is option 3.  If you look through the code itself, it's a line the maintainers want to remove, anyway, and how they're dealing with it is better, and in general with these things, I prefer to go forward (latest version of `flask-admin`) rather than holding things back (rollback `sqlalchemy` to a previous version), and certainly better than manually editing the raw code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue. I got the hacks (as described above) to work, but looking at the discussions on https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/373 and https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1588, it looked like support for wtforms_sqlalchemy is not as good as wtforms_alchemy.

So, I installed wtforms_alchemy

```
pip install wtforms_alchemy
```

and replaced wtforms_sqlalchemy with wtform_alchemy in my project

```
from wtforms_alchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
```

and my project worked the same.