# flask-wtf display join of two tables

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have two tables which I am joining together.

```
class Request(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    client = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('client.id'))
    offerSent = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    (...)

class Client(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(60))
    prename = db.Column(db.String(40))
    requests = db.relationship('Request', backref='requestClient',   lazy='dynamic')
(...)
```

So I am joining the two tables:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    results = db.session.query(Request, Client).filter(Request.client == Client.id).all()
    return render_template('index.html', title='Start', results=results)
```

And then I am displaying them:

```
{% block app_content %}

    <h4>User: {{ current_user.username }}!</h4>

    {% for i in range(0, results|length) %}
       {{ results[i][0].offerSent }} 
       {{ results[i][1].lastname }} 
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

So as you see I have to hardcode the second dimension to get the proper value out of the list (results = [( Request 1, Client 13), (...,...)].

Is there maybe a nicer way to do it? E.g. something like results.request.offerSent and results.client.lastname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use [tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops/10867891#10867891) within Jinja like this, which seems to be what you are looking for:

```
{% block app_content %}

    <h4>User: {{ current_user.username }}!</h4>

    {% for req, client in results %}
        {{ req.offerSent }} 
        {{ client.lastname }} 
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I used `req` here because Flask's `request` is part of the Jinja2 [standard context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-context)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" which I was fighting with many hours before. Do you have any idea? I am using SQLAlchemy-1.2.0b3 as there is a bug in 1.2.1 regarding a same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390207/sql-alchemy-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack?rq=1)  - even so I don't know if its related to the error regarding your post.

Comment: Yea I'm not familiar with this bug and it is impossible for me to test this, but I'd expect this to work if results is a list of tuples with 2 values... sorry this did not work!!

Comment: Forget the bug I was wrtiting about. I recreated the venv and installed all  requirements (latest versions) and now your solution is working fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: Terrific! Glad you got it sorted out. If you feel the post sufficiently answers your question you can "accept" it as the answer for future readers.